# IndexError: tuple index out of range error Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, tuples

```
data_train = data.loc['1970':'2000', 'Value'].to_numpy()
data_test = data.loc['2001', 'Value'].to_numpy()


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_train = scaler.fit_transform(data_train.reshape(-1,1))
data_test = scaler.transform(data_test.reshape(-1,1))


def data_preparation(data):
    x = []
    y = []
    
    for i in range(40, len(data)):
        x.append(data[i-40:i, 0])
        y.append(data[i])
        
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1)
    
    return x, y

x_train, y_train = data_preparation(data_train)

x_train.shape, y_train.shape

x_test, y_test = data_preparation(data_test)
```

All code works excluding `x_test, y_test = data_preparation(data_test)` then the following error appears:

```
> ERROR - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23852/2333899177.py in <module>
----> 1 x_test, y_test = data_preparation(data_test)

> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23852/1614433321.py in data_preparation(data)
     10     y = np.array(y)
     11 
---> 12     x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1)
     13 
     14     return x, y

> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that after:

```
    x = []
    y = []
    
    for i in range(40, len(data)):
        x.append(data[i-40:i, 0])
        y.append(data[i])
```

x is a one dimensional list. And therefore 'x.shape[1]' doesn't exist, that is index 1 is out of range.

If you rewrite

```
 x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1)
```

as

```
x = x.reshape(x.shape + (1,))
```

you'll be able to handle arbitrary shapes of x.